# Batch files - number of command line arguments

Tags: shell, batch-file, scripting

Just converting some shell scripts into batch files and there is one thing I can't seem to find...and that is a simple count of the number of command line arguments.

eg. if you have:

```
myapp foo bar
```

In Shell:

- $# -> 2
- $* -> foo bar
- $0 -> myapp
- $1 -> foo
- $2 -> bar

In batch

- **?? -> 2   <---- what command?!**
- %* -> foo bar
- %0 -> myapp
- %1 -> foo
- %2 -> bar

So I've looked around, and either I'm looking in the wrong spot or I'm blind, but I can't seem to find a way to get a count of number of command line arguments passed in.

Is there a command similar to shell's "$#" for batch files?

ps. the closest i've found is to iterate through the %1s and use 'shift', but I need to refernece %1,%2 etc later in the script so that's no good.

Comment: your string is `2 myapp foo bar` ?

Comment: advice:  don't convert sh into BAT.

instead, download cygwin and use it instead.  i.e. your sh scripts will work on a windows machine.  and you won't have to translate every sh to BAT!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Googling a bit gives you the following result from [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Programming_CMD):

```
set argC=0
for %%x in (%*) do Set /A argC+=1

echo %argC%
```

Seems like cmd.exe has evolved a bit from the old DOS days :)

Comment: Note that this variant of `for` only works for arguments that look like file names, not option strings such as `-?`.  Using quotes (`for %%i in ("%*") ...`) works for argument like `-?` but again fails for quoted arguments because of nested quotes.  The only robust way seems to involve `shift`...

Comment: `MyBatchFile "*.*" "Abc"` reports that argC == 9. -- Downvoted.

Comment: Have tested this out to 2500 arguments as a function and used it to define arrays of same size. Dont ask me why exactly. Mostly just learning what batch is capable of.

Comment: When a path (whether it is a file name or an intermediate directory name) contains a half-width comma but does not contain any half-width spaces, when the Windows system generates parameters (such as dragging the file icon to the batch file icon), it will not automatically Enclose such a path with double quotes, the path parameter will be incorrectly counted as two parameters.

For example, the path of a file is:
D:\a,b.txt
It would be wrongly split into the following two parameters:
D:\a
b.txt

Answer (score 57):

You tend to handle number of arguments with this sort of logic:

```
IF "%1"=="" GOTO HAVE_0
IF "%2"=="" GOTO HAVE_1
IF "%3"=="" GOTO HAVE_2
```

etc.

If you have more than 9 arguments then you are screwed with this approach though.  There are various hacks for creating counters which you can find [here](http://home7.inet.tele.dk/batfiles/batfiles.htm), but be warned these are not for the faint hearted.

Comment: You can still use `shift` to count more than 9 ... and without having 10 lines of equally-looking code.

Answer (score 24):

The function `:getargc` below may be what you're looking for.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
call :getargc argc %*
echo Count is %argc%
echo Args are %*
endlocal
goto :eof

:getargc
    set getargc_v0=%1
    set /a "%getargc_v0% = 0"
:getargc_l0
    if not x%2x==xx (
        shift
        set /a "%getargc_v0% = %getargc_v0% + 1"
        goto :getargc_l0
    )
    set getargc_v0=
    goto :eof
```

It basically iterates once over the list (which is local to the function so the shifts won't affect the list back in the main program), counting them until it runs out.

It also uses a nifty trick, passing the name of the return variable to be set by the function.

The main program just illustrates how to call it and echos the arguments afterwards to ensure that they're untouched:

```
C:\Here> xx.cmd 1 2 3 4 5
    Count is 5
    Args are 1 2 3 4 5
C:\Here> xx.cmd 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
    Count is 11
    Args are 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
C:\Here> xx.cmd 1
    Count is 1
    Args are 1
C:\Here> xx.cmd
    Count is 0
    Args are
C:\Here> xx.cmd 1 2 "3 4 5"
    Count is 3
    Args are 1 2 "3 4 5"
```

Comment: how can you alter the flow based on this? (may be a different question, but I think a short example would be also very convenient here!)

Comment: @n611x007 where the `echo Count is %argc%` you would insert your own code that could check if that count is proper and then move on.

Comment: This is broken in the same way as many approaches are: it does not work for command-line arguments containing special characters. For example, passing /? as the first argument leads to an error.

Comment: Unfortunately this fails for `xx.cmd /?`. The script then prints the help for `CALL` instead of calling `getargc`.

Comment: When a path (whether it is a file name or an intermediate directory name) contains a half-width comma but does not contain any half-width spaces, when the Windows system generates parameters (such as dragging the file icon to the batch file icon), it will not automatically Enclose such a path with double quotes, the path parameter will be incorrectly counted as two parameters.

For example, the path of a file is:
D:\a,b.txt
It would be wrongly split into the following two parameters:
D:\a
b.txt

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
SET /A ARGS_COUNT=0    
FOR %%A in (%*) DO SET /A ARGS_COUNT+=1    
ECHO %ARGS_COUNT%
```

Comment: is this answer somehow different from [@nimrod one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1292094/505893)?...

Comment: check comment by @FerdinandBeyer in nimrodm's. not gonna downvote because you have 21 rep 8)

Answer (score 9):

If the number of arguments should be an exact number (less or equal to 9), then this is a simple way to check it:

```
if "%2" == "" goto args_count_wrong
if "%3" == "" goto args_count_ok

:args_count_wrong
echo I need exactly two command line arguments
exit /b 1

:args_count_ok
```

Answer (score 3):

**A *reasonably robust* solution** is to delegate counting to a *subroutine* invoked with `call`; the subroutine uses `goto` statements to emulate a loop in which `shift` is used to consume the (subroutine-only) arguments iteratively:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal

:: Call the argument-counting subroutine with all arguments received,
:: without interfering with the ability to reference the arguments
:: with %1, ... later.
:: NOTE: See comments re /? below.
call :count_args %* >NUL || (echo Usage: ... & exit /b 0)

:: Print the result.
echo %ReturnValue% argument(s) received.

:: Exit the batch file.
exit /b

:: Subroutine that counts the arguments given.
:: Returns the count in %ReturnValue%
:count_args
  set /a ReturnValue = 0
  :count_args_for
    if %1.==. goto :eof
    set /a ReturnValue += 1
    shift
  goto count_args_for
```

**Limitations**:

- `/?` among the arguments - except if passed as `"/?"` - is *not* supported, because `call` *invariably* interprets it as a request to show *its* command-line help.

  - The code above detects this case (curiously, `call` signals failure via its exit code after showing its help) and interprets this case as wanting to show *the current batch file's help* instead of counting arguments.
- Arguments with metacharacters (special characters) *are* supported, if enclosed in `"..."` (as is typical), but character-individual `^`-escaping in an unquoted argument does *not* work (because the `^` is already stripped by the time the batch file sees the arguments, and expanding `%*` then causes the metacharacters to act as such):

  ```bash
  :: OK - arguments with special chars. are "..."-enclosed.
  :: -> "3 argument(s) received."
  test.cmd hi "you & me" "a<b"

  :: !! FAILS
  :: The last argument uses character-individual ^-escaping.
  :: -> error "The system cannot find the file specified."
  test.cmd hi "you & me" a^<b
  ```
- A syntactically invalid argument list is *not* supported (which is arguably not a problem):

  ```bash
  :: !! FAILS
  :: Syntactically invalid argument list
  :: -> error "The syntax of the command is incorrect."
  test.cmd a"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Avoids using either `shift` or a `for` cycle at the cost of size and readability.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a arg_idx=1
set "curr_arg_value="
:loop1
if !arg_idx! GTR 9 goto :done
set curr_arg_label=%%!arg_idx!
call :get_value curr_arg_value !curr_arg_label!
if defined curr_arg_value (
  echo/!curr_arg_label!: !curr_arg_value!
  set /a arg_idx+=1
  goto :loop1
)
:done
set /a cnt=!arg_idx!-1
echo/argument count: !cnt!
endlocal
goto :eof

:get_value
(
  set %1=%2
)
```

Output:

```
count_cmdline_args.bat testing more_testing arg3 another_arg

%1: testing
%2: more_testing
%3: arg3
%4: another_arg
argument count: 4
```

EDIT: The "trick" used here involves:

1. Constructing a string that represents a currently evaluated command-line argument variable (i.e. "%1", "%2" etc.) using a string that contains a percent character (`%%`) and a counter variable `arg_idx` on each loop iteration.
2. Storing that string into a variable `curr_arg_label`.
3. Passing both that string (`!curr_arg_label!`) and a return variable's name (`curr_arg_value`) to a primitive subprogram `get_value`.
4. In the subprogram its first argument's (`%1`) value is used on the left side of assignment (`set`) and its second argument's (`%2`) value on the right. However, when the second subprogram's argument is passed it is resolved into value of the main program's command-line argument by the command interpreter. That is, what is passed is not, for example, "%4" but whatever value the fourth command-line argument variable holds ("another_arg" in the sample usage).
5. Then the variable given to the subprogram as return variable (`curr_arg_value`) is tested for being undefined, which would happen if currently evaluated command-line argument is absent. Initially this was a comparison of the return variable's value wrapped in square brackets to empty square brackets (which is the only way I know of testing program or subprogram arguments which may contain quotes and was an overlooked leftover from trial-and-error phase) but was since fixed to how it is now.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @thewaywewere thank you, I keep forgetting that for many people (likely the majority) it is better to have a text description instead of "self-explanatory" code.

Comment: @fen-fire except that the code is not self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

The last answer was two years ago now, but I needed a version for more than nine command line arguments. May be another one also does...

```
@echo off
setlocal

set argc_=1
set arg0_=%0
set argv_=

:_LOOP
set arg_=%1
if defined arg_ (
  set arg%argc_%_=%1
  set argv_=%argv_% %1
  set /a argc_+=1
  shift
  goto _LOOP
)
::dont count arg0
set /a argc_-=1
echo %argc_% arg(s)

for /L %%i in (0,1,%argc_%) do (
  call :_SHOW_ARG arg%%i_ %%arg%%i_%%
)

echo converted to local args
call :_LIST_ARGS %argv_%
exit /b


:_LIST_ARGS
setlocal
set argc_=0
echo arg0=%0

:_LOOP_LIST_ARGS
set arg_=%1
if not defined arg_ exit /b
set /a argc_+=1
call :_SHOW_ARG arg%argc_% %1
shift
goto _LOOP_LIST_ARGS


:_SHOW_ARG
echo %1=%2
exit /b
```

The solution is the first 19 lines and converts all arguments to variables in a c-like style. All other stuff just probes the result and shows conversion to local args. You can reference arguments by index in any function.