# Using a .batch to change the calling cmd prompt's directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a .bat that calls a .vbs script in order to return a change directory command such as

```
cd /D ../../some/determined/path
```

But the problem seems that although the .bat file is changing directory, once execution ends, the command prompt remains where it started.

```
@echo cd_command: !cd_command!
cd !cd_command! 

REM Next line displays expected files for said directory
dir
```

My end goal is to have the original calling command prompt to change directory.

**How could I make the calling command prompt actually change directory through the .bat file?**

### Update

Seems I'm not being clear enough, and since I intend to release the code publicly I might as well post it here in full. (Although apprehensive about doing so for some reason?)

My end goal is this: I type in Win+R to open run command. Type cmd to get the prompt. and then type this bat file (which would be added to the environmental variables) so that I can do something like:

```
C:\Users\Mallow> cdj 20.2
C:\Users\Mallow\Documents\20-29 Areas\20 Category\2 Id>
```

I have this Bat file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Check only one parameter was passed
if not "%~2"=="" (
    echo No more than two arguments, please
    goto :eof
)

if not "%~1"=="" (
    echo "1"
REM     REM Use vbscript to interpret float string. 
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%r in (`CSCRIPT //NoLogo "cdj.vbs" %~1`) DO SET johnny_decimal_command=%%r
    echo command:
    @echo johnny_decimal: !johnny_decimal_command!

    REM This variable is the full command
    !johnny_decimal_command!

    REM Tests the output to see if the directory did change script level
    REM dir

) else (
    echo "2"
REM     REM No parameters passed
REM     echo Must pass in Johnny Decimal id. Example: 12.01 or 12; [Category.Optional ID]
REM     goto :eof
)

REM REFERENCES:
REM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880183/pass-value-from-vbscript-to-batch
REM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129085/how-to-return-a-string-from-a-vbscript-which-is-executed-from-a-python-file
REM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497985/batch-checking-the-number-of-parametersfg
REM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949978/why-does-this-batch-variable-never-change-even-when-set#3950000
REM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013428/pass-variable-from-batch-to-vbs
```

And this VBS Script:

```
Dim base_path
base_path = "C:\Users\Mallow\Documents\"

' Get passed arguments
dim oParameters
dim johnny_decimal

Set oParameters = WScript.Arguments
WScript.echo Main(oParameters.Item(0))

' Generates Johnny Decimal Command
Function Main(ByVal johnny_decimal)
    dim is_number
    dim has_category
    dim has_id
    dim johnny_command

    ' Check cdj is numeric
    if isnumeric(johnny_decimal) Then
        is_number = True
    else
        johnny_command = "echo Johnny Decimal passed is not a numerical value."
    end if


    if is_number then
        ' Check if number passed is integer or float
        if instr(1, johnny_decimal, ".") > 0 then
            has_category = True
            has_id = True
        else
            has_category = True
        end if
    end if

    if has_category Then
        dim area, category, id

        ' Prepare template for command
        johnny_command = base_path & "{area}*\{category}*\"

        ' Calculate Category and Area
        category = int(johnny_decimal)
        area = int(left(johnny_decimal,1) & "0")

        ' Put info into command
        johnny_command = replace(johnny_command, "{area}", area)
        johnny_command = replace(johnny_command, "{category}", category)

        If has_id Then

            ' Prepare template for command
            johnny_command = johnny_command & "{id}*"

            ' Calculate ID
            id = int((johnny_decimal - category) * 100)

            ' Make sure id has leading zero
            if len(id) = 1 then
                id = "0" & id
            end if

            ' Put info into command
            johnny_command = replace(johnny_command, "{id}", id)                    

        End If

        ' Prepend with change directory command and encapsulate in quotes
        johnny_command = "cd /D " & chr(34) & johnny_command & chr(34) 

    End If

    Main = johnny_command
End Function


'Set File = FSO.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0) &"\test.txt", 2, True)
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806713/ddg#2806731
```

The VBS Script is so that I can interpret the passed arguments as numbers (as it would always be an integer or float of format [00 or 00.00]

Comment: Excuse me: you want a batch to change your current folder to another one let's call it **x** folder. Then you want to run something which relies on this **x** folder. Is that correct? Anything I missed?

Comment: Why do you use a batch file at all on using mainly a VBScript executed by `%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe` (console version) or `%SystemRoot%\System32\wscript.exe` (Windows GUI version). Changing the current directory is also possible directly from within the Visual Basic Script. I suppose that you are using `setlocal` above the command line with `cd`. In this case explicitly or implicitly called `endlocal` restores initial current directory. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands __SETLOCAL__ and __ENDLOCAL__.

Comment: you are expanding on the variable, but I do not see that you have enabled `delayedexpansion`. Can you  post some more of your code please?

Comment: In other words you need `cd /D "%~dp0..\..\some\determined\path"` above the command line with `setlocal` to change the current directory path relative to path of batch file permanently. Please note that this works only for paths starting with a drive letter. In case of batch file is stored on a network resource accessed using UNC path, the command __CD__ does not change the directory as by default Windows prevents that a UNC path accessed directory becomes the current directory. Please note further that on Windows ``\`` is the directory separator and `/` is used for parameters.

Comment: Wait - you mean you are starting the batch file from command prompt, the batch file changes directory, but cmd remains in the directory where you started the batch file?

Comment: Hey y'all, thanks for commenting on my question. I've updated my question to include code and expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it

```
@echo johnny_decimal: !johnny_decimal_command!

!%johnny_decimal_command!
PushD .
EndLocal
Popd
```

Credit: [SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION causes CD and PUSHD to not persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246151/setlocal-enabledelayedexpansion-causes-cd-and-pushd-to-not-persist) 
Was easier for me to understand than the comment pointing to the node.js even though it comes out to the same things.