# Is redirection recognized as a argument when executing a script/program?

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, cmd

I have a batch-file program that gets called from another batch-file so I can redirect error output to a file. When you run the commmand `START /B "C:\Some\Script" 2>"C:\Some\Log.log"` Is the redirection recognized as an argument?

Just a question with no real usefulness (at least that I can tell), just asking out of curiousity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Try using this as your test script to verify:

```
set argC=0
for %%x in (%*) do Set /A argC+=1

echo %argC%
```

In that file, argC is the number of arguments. (Source: [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Programming_CMD#Command-Line_Interfacing), via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1292094/293511).)

Answer (score 2):

Ben is correct - redirection is not counted as an argument. The redirection is handled before the script is called.

As an alternative to counting the args as a test, you can simply look at the args that have been passed in to your script

```
echo %*
```

Another option when you use START or CMD /C is to echo %CMDCMDLINE% to see the exact line that was used to launch CMD (including the parameters). It is really handy sometimes to help diagnose parsing, escape and expansion issues. This is also handy when the instantiation of CMD is implicit such as with `FOR /F %%A IN ('command')` or `command1|command2` (each side of the pipe gets its own CMD session).

I'm curious why you are using `START /B script 2>logFile` instead of `CALL script 2>logFile`? They both should work, but I think the 2nd option is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: eh just using START for the example.