# How to shift arguments in batch files when there are more than 10 arguments

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I am learning how to write batch files for Windows 7 using the VBScript like native scripting language.

I suppose I am not using the Windows Scripting Host or the Power Shell. I am using the simple old style VBScript like syntax.

I don't understand how to shift arguments when there are more than 9 arguments (or 10 including the name of the batch file) passed to the batch file.

Could you please teach me that?

Let us assume that you called my batch file with the following arguments:

```
C:\>call my.bat "one" "two" "three" "four" 
    "five" "six" "seven" "eight" "nine" "ten" "eleven"
```

How would you access the arguments `ten` and `eleven` from within `my.bat`?

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/shift.html

Comment: @Kayasax Thank you. Can you please point me to an example where there were more than 10 arguments supplied to the batch file and it reads all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the batch taken from ss64.com

```
@echo off
:start
if "%1"=="" (goto :exit)
:: Do whatever with token %1
Echo [%1] 
:: Shift %2 into %1 
SHIFT
goto :start

:exit
::pause
```

call that batch with more than 10 arguments, it will display all

```
    shift.bat 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
[10]
[11]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Kayasax. (1) Are the lines starting with `::` comments? I only have seen comments start with `REM` so far, so I ask. (2) I understand that you are doing it 1 at a time and reading just the first one till all arguments have been read. If I had to do it using a for loop, I would have to know the exact total number of arguments passed to the batch file. Is there a method to look ahead and know in advance the total number of arguments passed to the batch file?

Comment: 1- yes these are comments. 2- see that post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291941/batch-files-number-of-command-line-arguments