# Batch File: Take parameters from n-th index to the last index

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a unlimited list of params a b c d e f g h....
I want to run a command in batch file as following:

```
mybatchfile a b c d e f g h I j k l m n ...
```

I have a program that I want to take params from d to the last. Do I can do this?
I know that %* will take all params. May I can exclude some params by this way?

Comment: use the `shift` command 3 times in your batch then %1 will match your d parameter. see example here : http://ss64.com/nt/shift.html

Comment: But how to get to the end. If I use %* after 3 times SHIFT, I also get the full list params.

Comment: use as many shift commands as the number of parameters you have to process. If you dont know the number use shift until %1=""

Comment: you also may use `shift /n` : Start at the nth argument, where n may be between zero and eight. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21546753/381149

Comment: Can you explain clearly? For example my list params is a b c d e f g h I j k l m n (14 params). I want take from d to n. How can I write without using %5 %6 %7....? I'm a newbie in batch file :(

Comment: i write example as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3,* delims= " %%a in ("%*") do set "params=%%d"
echo here are the parameters 4...n:
echo %params%
start myprogram %params%
```

Comment: @user3733276 - This will fail if any of the skipped parameters contain spaces. For example, if `%*` = `"partA partB" "arg2" "arg3" "arg4" "arg5"`, then it will produce `"arg3" "arg4" "arg5"`. The correct output would be `"arg4" "arg5"`.

Comment: @user3733276 - This also has problems if any arguments contain quoted special characters like `&` or `|`.

Answer (score 3):

your batch :

```
@echo off
rem remove 3 first args
SHIFT 
SHIFT
SHIFT

:start
if "%1"=="" (goto :exit)
:: Do whatever with token %1
Echo [%1] 
:: Shift %2 into %1 
SHIFT
goto :start

:exit
::pause
```

will output :

```
C:\temp>shift.bat a b c d e f g h i j k l m n
[d]
[e]
[f]
[g]
[h]
[i]
[j]
[k]
[l]
[m]
[n]
```

Comment: Yes, this code help us take params from d to n. Can you tell me how do I call for my command? I need a new list in order to I can call look like `myprogram list_new_param`?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Preserve first 3 arguments so they may be used elsewhere in the script, if needed.
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
set arg3=%3

:: Now build the argument list for the remaining arguments
shift /1
shift /1
shift /1
set "args="
:getArgs
if "%~1" neq "" (
  set args=%args% %1
  shift
  goto :getArgs
)

:: Call your program
yourProgram %args%

:: Carry on with the rest of your script, as needed
```

Don't forget to use `call yourProgram %args%` if your program is another batch script, otherwise it will not return.